# How the memory allocation is done for StringBuffer(" " + " " + " ")

Tags: java

`String` will always create new memory space, whereas `StringBuffer` will not, it will update the existing memory whenever we append with new value.

My question is: suppose, I use

```
new StringBuffer("A " + "B " + "C " + "D " + "E " + "F").toString();
```

how the memory allocation is done ?

Comment: String literals are appended using a StringBuffer during compilation.

Comment: @f1sh No, not in this case here.

Comment: You're not actually using the StringBuffer's appending mechanism here; the fact that you called `new StringBuffer` doesn't change how `"A " + "B " + "C " + "D " + "E " + "F"` works.

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler is smart enough to concatenate the String ABCDEF at compile time and load it as Compile time constant .. So it will be only one String created in the pool.

Answer (score 1):

Without the special-case optimization that @Neerav describes (so in an older JRE, or if you don't have literal strings), your code would end up with lots of CPU and memory overhead.

You have the expression `"A " + "B " + "C " + "D " + "E " + "F"`. That translates to (without the optimization)

```
new StringBuilder("A ").append("B ").append("C ").append("D ")
    .append("E ").append("F").toString()
```

The literal strings like `"A "` aren't allocated when your line of code is executed. They get pre-allocated into the string pool when your class is loaded.

Your code creates one `StringBuilder` (modern replacement for `StringBuffer`) and appends the characters to its buffer. So it allocates the `StringBuilder` base object plus a character array. Maybe the initial buffer wasn't big enough, then at some point `StringBuilder` has to allocate a new, bigger array, copy the characters from the old to the new array, and continue.

Finally the expression needs to be a `String` instead of `StringBuilder`, so you get a `toString()`. This creates a new `String` base object plus a new character array with exactly the correct size.

Then you wrap this expression in a `new StringBuffer(...).toString()`, which is completely unneccessary. First this creates a new `StringBuffer` base object plus a new character array big enough for your string and copies the characters over there. Then you call `toString()` on this `StringBuffer`, which creates another `String` base instance plus character array and copies the characters once more, into this new `String` object. You already had an exactly identical `String` before the `new StringBuffer(...).toString()`.

So, you allocate:

- 1 StringBuilder
- 2 Strings
- 1 StringBuffer
- including 4 character arrays (maybe more, if the StringBuilder's initial size didn't suffice)